# Update App name and tab arrangement before upgrading your manage package

Tags: apex, managed-package, package, upgrade

Good day everyone. I have a manage package. First, I try to  install my manage package.Few days later, I try to rename my app name and rearrange its tab, because I want this to be included during my upgrade. After that, I try to upgrade my instance to my latest manage package. The problem is that, the app name is still the same on the previous package and the tab arrangement is still the same with the previous package. In short, all those changes like renaming app name does not affect after the upgrade. What is the explanation of this? Do I miss something ? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not all components are upgradable

You can look at the table of this page:

[Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm)

The main reason for that is that these components can be changed on the client's org, therefore cannot be re-changed by upgrading package.